# Introduction of interfaces only for unit test mocks legitimate?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, dependencies

I am currently working on a C# software component which will be integrated as a framework into other software products. Currently there are only a few unit tests, which I would like to change. In the process I have encountered a problem:

A large part of the classes are not visible outside the framework, i.e. not part of the public API. Therefore they are set to "internal" by the access modifier. Due to the complex subject matter, these internal classes are often interwoven with other classes (via injection) and cannot be instantiated "just like that", but must in some cases be generated from complex byte streams.

To break up this problem, I would switch to the situation that each of these internal classes gets its own interface. In principle I would not do this for internal classes, because in all cases, where there is no interface yet, there will be no modification of a class. So why an interface?

Disadvantage in my eyes is that I let the number of interfaces explode extremely and there is practically only one implementation for each interface. Also the code tracking in IDEs is more difficult, because you often have to jump to the interface first and then find the implementation of the interface.

The newly inserted interface would practically only be there to map the dependencies with mocks in unit tests. At this point, however, I'm not sure if this is really the way to approach it or if there is a better strategy.

Comment: So, baseline is: you have a Lib that's not been designed to be (unit-) testable. And now you want it to be unit-tested. And now you want advice on how to make spaghetti-lib testable without putting in too much effort? Is it that?

Comment: I used to work for a company that had almost every class implemented an interface, even if it was for the sole purpose of testability (except for DTOs, of course). It was kind of annoying at first but once you get used to it, it's really not that bad.

Comment: @Fildor I search for the right way to do it. If the right approach is to introduce the interfaces, then I have no problem with that.

Comment: I see. Well, the "problem" with _that_ is: there probably isn't **the** "right" way. There might be "easier" and "complex" ways to achieve different sets of goals ... and it isn't perfectly clear, what exactly you want to achieve. Yes, "introducing (more) unit tests" - ok. But are you aiming for 100% code coverage? 90%, 80%? Happy-Path? Edge-Cases? Happy Path & Edge Cases? ... For either goal, you may want to accept different levels of effort, you see?

Answer (score 0):

I think it sound like a legitimate case for introducing interfaces to make the code testable. This will at least get you in a better position for making other changed to the legacy code base.

If you have not yet read it I can recommend `Working Effectively with Legacy Code` by Feathers.